# Displaying images in recycler view, android studio

Tags: java, android

So i am making a contact list type app and for the time being just want to show an image on the left of the name, my main xml for the view is this. I know the code is big and all however the name part is being displayed correctly and i only wanna fix the images not showing.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="326dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="326dp"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/android" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/c_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="57dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="57dp"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:text="Contact Name"
    android:textSize="25dp" />
```

the adapter class is this

public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private ArrayList<ContactProvider> arrayList = new ArrayList<ContactProvider>();

public ContactAdapter(ArrayList<ContactProvider> arrayList){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout,parent,false);

    RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
    return recyclerViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {

    ContactProvider contactProvider = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(contactProvider.getImg_res());
    holder.c_name.setText(contactProvider.getC_name());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView c_name;
    ImageView imageView;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        c_name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.c_name);
    }
}
```

}

Finally my mainactivity.java

```
RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

String[] c_name;
int[] Img_res = {R.drawable.android};
ArrayList<ContactProvider> arrayList = new ArrayList<ContactProvider>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    c_name = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Contact_name);
    int i = 0;

    for (String name: c_name )
    {
        ContactProvider contactProvider = new ContactProvider(Img_res[0],name);
        arrayList.add(contactProvider);
        i++;
    }
    adapter = new ContactAdapter(arrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

the image i want to add i have kept in drawable (android.jpg).

The names are comming properly its just the image giving the problem.

Comment: Are you sure that `ImageView` is even on-screen? `android:layout_marginEnd="326dp"` - That's a pretty big margin.

Comment: @MikeM. just changed marginright to 0 and its still not showing in app (it does show in the design/preview tab of android studio though)

Comment: not only right both right and end ...

Comment: @SantanuSur if i change the end one then it messes the position of image wrt the text i wanna keep.

Comment: and also are u sure `contactProvider.getImg_res()` is a valid image ??

Comment: @SantanuSur ok so changing both to 0 made the img visible but the position is messed up, like its comming in the middle of the screen instead of to the left hand side.

Comment: If you want it on the left, why are you aligning it to the right/end? `android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"`, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. It might be simpler for you to use a `LinearLayout` for this.

Comment: @MikeM.ohh, ok so how do i fix that? do i do alignParentLeft = true ? or something else? im kinda new so ssry

Comment: In a `RelativeLayout`, children align to the left/start and the top by default, so you wouldn't need to specify that; just remove the right/end alignments. If it were me, though, I would just use a `LinearLayout` for this, rather than trying to fiddle with `RelativeLayout`. Change the `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout`, then remove all of the `layout_align*` and `layout_toRightOf` attributes on the `ImageView` and `TextView`. The `ImageView` will then automatically be to the left of the `TextView`, by virtue of how `LinearLayout` works. You can adjust the margins as needed.

Comment: @MikeM. hey thanks for all the help, i fixed it, instead of end and right swapped to start and left but the main thing that fixed was to limit the width to 60dp instead of match_parent or wrap_content.